# complex limit problem

Tags: limits

> If $m,n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x^m)^n-(1+x^n)^m}{x^2}$ is

what i try

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\bigg[1+nx^m+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^{2m}+\cdots\bigg]-\bigg[1+mx^n+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}x^{2n}+\cdots\bigg]}{x^2}$$

How do i solve it Help me

Comment: Best to find the Highest order of the top part, which we know is less than $mn$ since the first and second expansion cancel

Comment: Is L'Hospital allowed? And perhaps you can then first try this problem with some given $m,n$ and see "the flow of the numbers ". Considering the denominator, you may have to apply L'hospital twice if the limit exists.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x^m)^n-(1+x^n)^m}{x^2}. $$
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+nx^m)-(1+mx^n)}{x^2}\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}n [x^{m-2}-mx^{n-2}].$$  For the limit to exist at least one of $m$ and $n$ has to be $>2$. This limit will exist  when $m=2$ and $n>2$, then $L=n$, or when $n=2$ and $m>2$, then $L=-m.$ Also the limit is 0, when $m,n>2.$